# jqgrid multisielect option

Tags: checkbox, jqgrid, multi-select

I have used multiselect before in jqgrid but this time when I am adding multiselect option in a grid, all the checkboxes are populating as checked when grid is loaded. I only added `multiselect: true`. I tried below 2 statements in `gridComplete` and it is unchecking the checkboxes on grid load but when i am trying to check any checkboxe then it is taking 2 clicks to do the same. Its is like invisibly all the checkboxes are still checked.
`$('.cbox').attr('checked', false);
$('.cbox').click();`
 
Also the grid is having its option for subgrid enabled so can this be the issue? Kindly help.

Comment: You should post which version of jqGrid and from which fork ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7) you use. You should post the demo (in JSFiddle for example), which reproduce the problem with initial selection or at least post the JavaScript code, which you use.

Answer (score 0):

Its because all the checkboxes in the grid has the class `cbox`. So when you select using `$('.cbox')` its affecting all the checkboxes.

Instead of this

```
$('.cbox').attr('checked', false);
$('.cbox').click();
```

Try this

```
$('#cb_YourGridID').attr('checked', false);
$('.cb_YourGridID').click();
```

`$('.cb_YourGridID')` will point only to the checkbox on the header.

Note: `YourGridId` is the id of your table to which you bind jqgrid.